# Is it possible to detect if a POST action is for a "Save Post" before the save_post action?

Tags: redirect, save-post

What I need to do is inspect the content of the post and title and based on the inspection, redirect to a different page. To do this, I need to know if a "POST" action is for saving a post. How to detect this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Plugin API/Action Reference: Actions Run During an Admin Page Request.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Then add something simple to the appropriate hook:

```
function wpse19260_inspect_post()
{
    echo '<pre>';
        // print_r( $_POST );
        echo $_POST->ID;
        echo $_POST->post_content;
        echo $_POST->post_title
    echo '<pre>';
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'wpse19260_inspect_post' );
```